# Does $\mathcal{O}_X\text{-Mod}$ have enough projectives?

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be an integral, affine scheme. Are there any errors in the following argument that $\mathcal{O}_X\text{-Mod}$ does not have enough projectives?

---

Suppose $\mathcal{P}$ is projective and $\rho: \mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is a surjection. Then there is a surjection $\rho_x:\mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for any $x \in X$ (throughout, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regarded as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module supported at $x$).

Let $ 0 \neq \sigma \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for some $x \in X$. Then there is an open $V \subset X$ and $s \in \Gamma(V,\mathcal{P})$ such that $\rho_x(V)(s)=\sigma$. Choose an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $V \not\subset U$. Let $\mathcal{O}_U$ denote $i_!(\mathcal{O}_X|_U)$, where $i:U \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion. Then there is a surjection $r_x:O_U \rightarrow O_{X,x}$. Since $\mathcal{P}$ is projective, there is a lifting $\tau:\mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_U$ such that $\rho_x = r_x \circ \tau$.

Since $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_U)=0$, $\tau(V) = 0$. Thus $\sigma = \rho_x(V)(s) = r_x(V)(\tau(V)(s))=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by surjections $\rho_x:\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $r_x:\mathcal{O}_U\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ ? In each of these maps, the source is a sheaf on $X$, the target a stalk. I think you mean $x_*\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Also beware that $i_!(\mathcal{O}_X|_U)(V)$ might be non zero even if $V\not\subset U$. This is an important mistake since then your argument would work for any ringed space, but there are ringed spaces with enough projective. But for your case, it can be easily fixed : you can indeed choose $U$ such that $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_U)=0$.

Comment: @Roland In the question, I have clarified what I mean by $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. As for your second point, I don't follow it. Since $X$ is an integral scheme, $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_U)=0$ for any $U \not \supset V$. See the argument here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682649/81996

Comment: As usual, a way to see what is wrong is to pick the simplest instance where it proves something wrong and see what breaks. As the spectrum of a field is certainly integral and affine, and since modules over that are just vector spaces, of which all are projective, it seems like a good test case. As a rule, always, always consider the simplest possible example of anything.

Comment: @rj7k8 Ok for the first part I skipped the relevant sentence, my bad. As for the second, while I agree that this is true in most cases, there is an argument to be written explicitly ! This is not obvious and this is were you use that $X$ is integral. As Eric Wofsey pointed out, this fails for the spectrum of a field. But it also for fails for a product of these (in which case you may find $V\not\subset U$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is almost correct except that there may not exist any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $V\not\subseteq U$.  For instance, what if $V=\{x\}$?

Indeed, the result you are trying to prove is not true.  For instance, if $X$ is Spec of a field, then $\mathcal{O}_X\text{-Mod}$ is the category of vector spaces over the field, in which every object is projective.  Your argument does prove that the result is true if there exists a point $x\in X$ which has no smallest open neighborhood, since then your $U$ is guaranteed to exist.